# Terraform AWS RDS unable to get public external access

Tags: postgresql, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

I have created an aws rds instance with terraform using terraform-aws-modules. I need to be able to connect to the rds postgres instance from external ip addresses. My issue is when I try to connect with psql is hangs and timeouts out with the following error:

my connection:

```
psql -h postgress-rds-external-instance.ch3jsdgkjsd.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com -p 5432 -U postgadmin -d postgres -W
```

error

```
psql: error: connection to server at "postgress-rds-external-instance.ch3jsdgkjsd.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com" (54.244.16.262), port 5432 failed: Operation timed out
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

Here is my terraform code:

VPC

```
module "vpc" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version = "~> 5.0"

  # VPC Basic Details
  name            = var.vpc_name
  cidr            = "10.0.0.0/16"
  azs             = ["us-west-2b", "us-west-2c"]
  private_subnets = ["10.0.1.0/24", "10.0.2.0/24"]
  public_subnets  = ["10.0.101.0/24", "10.0.102.0/24"]

 # Database Subnets
  create_database_subnet_group       = true
  create_database_subnet_route_table = true
  database_subnets                   = ["10.0.151.0/24", "10.0.152.0/24"]

  #create_database_nat_gateway_route = true
  #create_database_internet_gateway_route = true

  # NAT Gateways - Outbound Communication
  enable_nat_gateway = true
  single_nat_gateway = true

  # VPC DNS Parameters
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  enable_dns_support   = true


  public_subnet_tags = var.public_subnet_tags

  private_subnet_tags = var.private_subnet_tags

  database_subnet_tags = var.database_subnet_tags

  tags = var.tags

  vpc_tags = var.vpc_tags
}
```

Security Group

```
module "rds_sg" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/security-group/aws"
  version = "5.1.0"

  name        = "rds-sg"
  description = "Security Group for RDS access"
  vpc_id      = module.vpc.vpc_id

  

  # Ingress Rules
  ingress_rules = ["postgresql-tcp", "openvpn-udp", "openvpn-tcp", "openvpn-https-tcp"]

  # CIDR Blocks for Ingress
  ingress_cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0", module.vpc.vpc_cidr_block] # Allow access from all IP addresses. Adjust as needed.

  # Egress Rule - all-all open
  egress_rules = ["all-all"]


}
```

DB

```
module "postgres" {
  source                         = "terraform-aws-modules/rds/aws" // Source of the module
  version                        = "5.9.0"                         // Version of the module
  identifier                     = "postg-rds-external-instance"
  instance_use_identifier_prefix = true
  engine                         = "postgres"
  engine_version                 = "14"
  family                         = "postgres14" # DB parameter group
  major_engine_version           = "14"         # DB option group
  instance_class                 = "db.t4g.micro"
  create_db_option_group         = true
  create_db_parameter_group      = true
  allocated_storage              = 5
  db_name                        = "postgdb"
  username                       = "postgadmin"
  password                       = "pS6sdfdsfdsfdsdfs"
  port                           = 5432
  publicly_accessible            = true
  db_subnet_group_name           = module.vpc.database_subnet_group_name
  subnet_ids                     = module.vpc.database_subnets
  vpc_security_group_ids         = [module.rds_sg.security_group_id]
  maintenance_window             = "Mon:00:00-Mon:03:00"
  backup_window                  = "03:00-06:00"
  backup_retention_period        = 0
  storage_encrypted              = true
  skip_final_snapshot            = true
  deletion_protection            = false
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing the RDS instance is in the private subnet? If so, you could use a bastion host.

Comment: yes but I tried in public subnet and it didnt work either

Comment: And the security groups allow 5432 from outside of AWS?

Comment: You need to uncomment `#create_database_internet_gateway_route = true` in the VPC module configuration, in order to make the DB Subnets public.